# Register ContentProvider only if authority does not exist

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm developing a custom home screen launcher. As part of its functionality I would like to be able to show unread notification badges.

Instead of implementing my own API for this, I would like to hook onto existing standards. The most widely used is the one for Samsung's TouchWiz launcher.

It works through a ContentProvider with the authority `com.sec.badge`. Now, on Samsung devices, I can easily use a ContentObserver to observe changes to Samsung's ContentProvider and it works perfectly. However, on devices without an existing ContentProvider (i.e. non-Samsung devices) I would like to provide my own ContentProvider for this purpose. This also works perfectly to capture inserts from other apps.

However, when I roll my own ContentProvider I naturally get an `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` error when trying to install on Samsung devices.

I fully understand *why* this is happening since Android wants to avoid having conflicts in the providers.

What I would want help with is a workaround. Is it possible to somehow register my ContentProvider dynamically instead of declaring it in `AndroidManifest.xml`? That way, I could first check if the authority is already taken, and if so go with an Observer. Otherwise, register my own ContentProvider and go with that.

I realize that this might be bad practice but I don't really see any other way. Some apps (such as Facebook) also implement Sony's badge API that works through Broadcasts which avoids conflict, but not nearly as many existing apps use this process.

I've tried this:

```
ContentProvider test = new SamsungContentProviderSpoof();
ProviderInfo providerInfo = new ProviderInfo();
providerInfo.authority = "com.sec.badge";
providerInfo.enabled = true;
providerInfo.exported = true;
test.attachInfo(this, providerInfo);
```

but that obviously fails. I guess I need to somehow access some system ContentResolver and register myself there, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to hook onto existing standards

There are no existing standards. A few vendors have done their own thing, and that's it.

> The most widely used is the one for Samsung's TouchWiz launcher.

Note that this mechanism is undocumented (AFAICT) and unsupported (outside of select Samsung partners).

> Is it possible to somehow register my ContentProvider dynamically instead of declaring it in AndroidManifest.xml? That way, I could first check if the authority is already taken, and if so go with an Observer. Otherwise, register my own ContentProvider and go with that.

You are welcome to say that it is disabled (`android:enabled="false"`) in the manifest, then conditionally enable it later using `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. You would know that you needed to do this by either trying to communicate with the existing provider (e.g., registering your observer) and getting an expected error, or by interrogating `PackageManager` to see if the provider exists.

However, not only will you need to claim that you are Samsung in terms of the provider, but also in terms of the custom permissions. *That* will break on the "L" Developer Preview, and probably going forward, for much the same reason that you ran into with the conflicting provider. At the present time, there is no workaround for this that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks!

By "existing standards" I did not mean an official Android standard, but the standards set by various existing third party launchers such as TouchWiz.

I will try your solution! Do you think you can expand a bit on how the custom permissions will break in L?

Thanks again!

Comment: @erikh: You ran into the problem where if an existing installed app defines an authority string, no new apps can be installed that define the same authority string. Similarly, starting with "L", if an existing installed app defines a custom permission (e.g., `com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE`), no new apps can be installed that define the same custom permission, unless they are signed by the same signing key (which won't be the case in your instance).

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks!

Hmm, okay, maybe I have to rethink this. It's just so convenient to use Samsung's previous functionality since a lot of present apps use it, but it does seem awfully hacky.

I'll mark your answer as accepted as soon as I've had time to test it out.

Comment: @erikh: From my quick glances at some of the alternatives, it looked like other manufacturers used broadcasts. IMHO, a broadcast is a better solution for this sort of a problem, as it is a loosely-coupled communications protocol and so is more amenable to zero/one/several implementations on either side of the protocol. If one or more vendors respond to certain "please set a badge for me" broadcasts, ones that do not require a custom permission, you might consider switching to those.

Comment: Yeah, I've implemented broadcasts too. Sony, HTC and the Apex launcher utilize broadcasts so I've implemented those and it works fine.

However, the Samsung solution is more widely used among other apps (or at least among the ones I've tried with), so that's why I wanted to implement that too. I agree that a broadcast is a much better solution otherwise, so I will probably end up not implementing the ContentProvider after all.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Alright, so after testing, it seems that I get an INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER despite setting android:enable=false for the provider.

I'll skip this step and hope that more apps implement broadcasts instead!

Thanks again!

Comment: @erikh: "Alright, so after testing, it seems that I get an INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER despite setting android:enable=false for the provider" -- really? That's odd. I thought I had tested this scenario a couple of years ago. I'd consider that a bug, to be honest. While your scenario is a trifle unusual, there are others where there might be a provider conflict. Sorry that didn't work out for you.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I was a bit uncomfortable with posing as Samsung anyway. I'll rely as much as I can on the other vendor's Broadcasts instead. I did however implement the ContentObserver for Samsung so on Samsung devices it will work.

Comment: @erikh: FWIW, I was able to reproduce your `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` problem, so it's not something unique to Samsung. I have filed [a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77613) on this, in case you're interested.

Comment: I've starred the bug report. Thanks for showing such interest!